# Listener not working for firebase datareference in java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger
/**
*
* @author adnan
*/
public class Json_Reader {

private final static Logger log
        = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

public static void intializeFirebase() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    FileInputStream serviceAccount =
            new FileInputStream("/home/adnan/Downloads/cryleticstest-firebase-adminsdk-avbul-f5ea5a09ca.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://cryleticstest.firebaseio.com")
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    System.out.println(FirebaseApp.getApps());
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
            Object object = dataSnapshot.getValue(Object.class);
            String json = new Gson().toJson(object);
            log.info(json);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            log.info("error");

        }
    });


}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    intializeFirebase();

}
 }
```

I am trying to connect my firebase database and fetch the JSON structure from there.
But the Listener in my ref(reference variable) is not working. The program gets connected to the Firebase console I guess but it does not fetch anything I assume as the listener is not working.
None of the method onDataChanged or onCancelled is working.
[image: Snapshot of my Firebase realtime Database,]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly the Java program will exit without waiting for the data to be loaded. You'll have to explicitly make it wait by using some Java synchronization primitive, such as:

```
final CountDownLatch sync = new CountDownLatch(1);

DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
        Object object = dataSnapshot.getValue(Object.class);
        String json = new Gson().toJson(object);
        log.info(json);
        sync.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        log.info("error");
        sync.countDown();
    }
});

sync.await();
```

Also see:

- [Firebase with java (non-android) retrieve information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098006/firebase-with-java-non-android-retrieve-information)
- [Listener's onDataChange() is not called by Firebase. Could not use new Google-Firebase on Java client, not Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350775/listeners-ondatachange-is-not-called-by-firebase-could-not-use-new-google-fi)
- [Firebase Java Admin SDK don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43700008/209103)

Comment: Great Answer! Thanks